# Geometry Nodes: How to scale edges along the normals of (unrelated) faces of the same mesh?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I instanced a profile on a curve. Then i selected certain faces and made them red.

I want to move a set of edges along the normals of the red faces.
Using **sample index** to extract the normals of the red faces does not work for some reason (changing the scale of the **vector math (scale)** node has no effect). Why?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Use **corners of vertixes node** + **face of corner node** to obtain the index of the faces with the relevant normals. Play around with **sort index** to get proper normals. no material index node needed.
Thanks @Crantisz

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set position node moves vertices, so normals are coming from vertices. To get normal from face, you should transfer from vertex domain to face domain.

To do this, you have to use topology nodes, that can get face of vertex thought corner:

[image]

since you have used materials there is a more elegant way to sort corners by material index

[image]

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding, your solution moves the red faces, i just want to move the top edges marked by the blue line in the picture along the normals of the red faces. @Crantisz

Comment: can you elaborate what the "material index - 0" is for? I tried other numbers, even ones exceeding the number of materials and it seems to work as long as it is "substract". weird